# Drawing lines on dynamically added canvases

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set up a script to draw lines on dynamically added canvases, so there could be any number of canvases on the page. This is the script for the code so far, but it's not showing the lines or drawing when clicked on. I think the issue is in the drawLine function. The canvases will be added via a second script which also adds other elements.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Variables to keep track of the mouse position and left-button status 
var mouseX,mouseY,mouseDown=0;

// Variables to keep track of the touch position
var touchX,touchY;

function drawLine(ctx,x,y,size) {

    // If lastX is not set, set lastX and lastY to the current position 
    if (lastX==-1) {
        lastX=x;
    lastY=y;
    }

    // Let's use black by setting RGB values to 0, and 255 alpha (completely opaque)
    r=0; g=0; b=0; a=255;

    // Select a fill style
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+(a/255)+")";

    // Set the line "cap" style to round, so lines at different angles can join into each other
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    //ctx.lineJoin = "round";


    // Draw a filled line
    ctx.beginPath();

// First, move to the old (previous) position
ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);

// Now draw a line to the current touch/pointer position
ctx.lineTo(x,y);

    // Set the line thickness and draw the line
    ctx.lineWidth = size;
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.closePath();

// Update the last position to reference the current position
lastX=x;
lastY=y;
}

// Get the current mouse position relative to the top-left of the canvas
function getMousePos(e) {
    if (!e)
        var e = event;

    if (e.offsetX) {
        mouseX = e.offsetX;
        mouseY = e.offsetY;
    }
    else if (e.layerX) {
        mouseX = e.layerX;
        mouseY = e.layerY;
    }
 }

// Get the touch position relative to the top-left of the canvas
// When we get the raw values of pageX and pageY below, they take into account the scrolling on the page
// but not the position relative to our target div. We'll adjust them using "target.offsetLeft" and
// "target.offsetTop" to get the correct values in relation to the top left of the canvas.
function getTouchPos(e) {
    if (!e)
        var e = event;

    if(e.touches) {
        if (e.touches.length == 1) { // Only deal with one finger
            var touch = e.touches[0]; // Get the information for finger #1
            touchX=touch.pageX-touch.target.offsetLeft;
            touchY=touch.pageY-touch.target.offsetTop;
        }
    }
}

// Keep track of the mouse button being released
function sketchpad_mouseUp() {
    mouseDown=0;
}


// Set-up an individual sketchpad and add our event handlers
// Use the "this" reference to make sure variables and functions are specific to each 
// specific sketchpad created in the "init()" function below.
function sketchpad(my_sketchpad) {

    // Get the specific canvas element from the HTML document passed
    this.canvas = document.getElementById(my_sketchpad);

    // If the browser supports the canvas tag, get the 2d drawing context for this canvas,
    // and also store it with the canvas as "ctx" for convenience
    if (this.canvas.getContext)
        this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');


    // Declare some functions associated with a particular sketchpad
    // We will attach these to the canvas as event handlers later
    // Note that the sketcphad_mouseUp function is not included here, since it's not 
    // specific to a certain canvas - we're listening to the entire window for mouseup
    // events.

    // Clear the canvas context using the canvas width and height
    this.clearCanvas = function() {
        this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }

    // Draw something when a touch start is detected
    this.sketchpad_touchStart = function() {
        // Update the touch co-ordinates
        getTouchPos();

        drawLine(this.ctx,touchX,touchY,12);

        // Prevents an additional mousedown event being triggered
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    // Draw something and prevent the default scrolling when touch movement is detected
    this.sketchpad_touchMove = function(e) { 
        // Update the touch co-ordinates
        getTouchPos(e);

        // During a touchmove event, unlike a mousemove event, we don't need to check if the touch is engaged, since there will always be contact with the screen by definition.
        drawLine(this.ctx,touchX,touchY,12); 

        // Prevent a scrolling action as a result of this touchmove triggering.
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    // Keep track of the mouse button being pressed and draw a dot at current location
    this.sketchpad_mouseDown = function() {
        mouseDown=1;
        drawLine(this.ctx,mouseX,mouseY,12);
    }

    // Keep track of the mouse position and draw a dot if mouse button is currently pressed
    this.sketchpad_mouseMove = function(e) { 
        // Update the mouse co-ordinates when moved
        getMousePos(e);

        // Draw a dot if the mouse button is currently being pressed
        if (mouseDown==1) {
            drawLine(this.ctx,mouseX,mouseY,12);
        }
    }

// Add event handlers
    // Check that we have a valid context to draw on/with before adding event handlers
    if (this.ctx) {
        // React to mouse events on the canvas, and mouseup on the entire document
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', this.sketchpad_mouseDown.bind(this), false);
        this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', this.sketchpad_mouseMove.bind(this), false);

        // React to touch events on the canvas
        this.canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', this.sketchpad_touchStart.bind(this), false);
        this.canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', this.sketchpad_touchMove.bind(this), false);
    }

}

// Create two sketchpads when the page loads, using our canvas elements called sketchpad1 and sketchpad2
function init() {
    sketch1 = new sketchpad('sketchpad1');
    //sketch2 = new sketchpad('sketchpad2');

    // Since we are listening to the entire window for the mouseup, it only needs to be done once per page,
    // and not once per canvas
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', sketchpad_mouseUp, false);
}
```

Comment: you have some undefined variables `var touchX, touchY, lastX = -1, lastY = -1;` but you have to put the inside the object "sketchpad" , because fo the multiple canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your troubles have nothing to do with the how the canvases are added.

```
var touchX,touchY;
```

Should be:

```
var touchX,touchY,lastX=-1,lastY=-1;
```